# How to start a crowd-funding application using Paypal's Parallel Payments method?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am building  a crowd funding application for my client for which I would like to use PayPal's Crowdfunding payment method using Pre-approved payment with Parallel Payments. To use this method, what is the process to register the application with PayPal? Can I test this method using PayPal sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to apply for adaptive payments:

- Go to Developer.paypal.com.
- Click **Dashboard** at the top of the
  screen.
  -Click **Create and manage Classic API apps** at the bottom of
  the page.
- Sign into the PayPal Account you would like to associate
  the application with (the PayPal account that Adaptive Payments will
  be used with).
  -Click **New Application**.
  -Fill out application. Use:
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/
  for assistance in filling out the application.
  -Click **Submit App** to submit the application for review.

And then you may also test in the sandbox.